# C#/.NET - config for server vs. localhost based on settings within web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have an C#/ASP.NET project which uses some `handlers` and `modules` in the `system.webServer` section of `web.config` for single-sign-on stuff which are necessary to be used on production server, but are not needed (and not wanted) to be used on localhost (I just get blank screens instead of my project on localhost).

Easy solution is to have two `web.config` files, but most settings are the same and changes would have to be updated in two `web.config` files, so I'd prefer to have just one. A workaround would be to comment the corresponding lines in the `web.config` when developing on localhost and uncomment them when deploying - but that's not really a nice solution.

Similar problem with database which is a different one on localhost.

Is there a simple way for having one `web.config` and do something like `if (!isLocalhost) use handler/module` within `web.config` file? I hoped for something in `preCondition` or similar parameter of `modules` and `filter` settings, but didn't find anything suitable.

Another idea could be to have something in the `app.settings` part - you could have a line like `<add key="myTrigger" value="true" />` and make an action in your controller dependent on the setting of `myTrigger` by testing `System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myTrigger"] == "true"` - this may be suitable for making the controller dependent on whether it's running on server vs. localhost, but for settings like `connectionStrings` this won't help too much - unless there's a way to have settings like `<whateversetting ... when appsetting.myTrigger == "true">` (but I doubt that something like that exists).

Another idea could be using external config files, e.g., `<connectionStrings configSource="some.config" />` which just have the differing parts of your `web.config` - so one local *some.config* and one on the server.

I'd prefer to have an *all-in-one-web.config* but that doesn't seem to be possible - unless YOU have a great idea.

So: What's best practice for this situation?

Answer (score 1):

I've had good success with having a local config file that is not under the normal web site directory. So do deploy you can blow away the web site directory without having to remember to keep the one file. So something like:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="..\ServerConfigs\ConnectionStrings.config"/>
```

I also move all of my application settings (except for the environment you are in) into the database.  See my blog post [here](http://blog.digitaltools.com/post/2009/02/25/Moving-AppSettings-to-a-Database-Table.aspx) There are 2 key benefits. First, you can move the production database down to development and not need to  change anything because all values for all environment are in 1 table. The second benefit is that it is easy to put in a hidden web page that you can go to and view all of the setting for a site.

Comment: +1 for keeping the local.config away the web site directory, that's fine for connection strings; moving settings to the database seems a bit weird, the main differences I have are from modules / handlers that come from single-sign-on software - I don't have to care about these things when they're in the web.config, but I would have to care when they are in the database; for other settings this may be a good approach - and having a (hidden) web page for viewing the settings sounds like a security risk to me (I wouldn't set up such a page)

Comment: @outofmind the "hidden" page has a URL like "mysite.com/admin/gttg" and you have to be logged in as an Admin, so it isn't as risky as it sounds.